Should I increment the MAJOR number in Semantic Versioning when I change the flow of the app?
We are developing a web application and we are in the version 1.2.0.
In the next release we will change the flow of the app by removing 2 pages and making other pages as Modals and change the user flow, and collapsing some components into one component.
Can we consider the next version as Major and it will be 2.0.0 because the flow is changed a little bit.

Semantic versioning is really about API compatibility, not anything user facing. What version you use for your web app is much more a marketing decision than a technical one.

Thank you @PhilipKendall, what do you suggest for versioning our app from technical perspective?

I suggest "versioning [y]our app from a technical perspective" is something you don't need to worry about.

But I'm not building content website, It's web app.

Same difference. It's consumed by humans, not by computers.

I'd recommend reading the accepted answer on the duplicate. If that doesn't answer your question, you should edit this question to differentiate it. As I see it, if that answer was posted here, it would also be the correct answer, which makes these two questions duplicates.
